# What does \flrow@restyle do?

Tags: floatrow

For a long time, I [had an issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133127/8425) when using the [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package together with the `twocolumn` option of the `article` class. [I did solve the problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159540/8425) by trial and error but I'd like to understand what I did and if my workaround has some side effects.

So, my question is: what does `\flrow@restyle` do and why is it redefining `\textwidth` to `\columnwidth`?

@David Carlisle [told me this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14284688#14284688) (and triggered this new question):

> I would guess that after `\textwidth\columnwidth` latex tries to fit
>   two columns into `\textwidth` (because that's what it normally does)
>   and finds that they don't fit as `\textwidth` has been made only wide
>   enough for one. I suppose the question is, what was the package trying
>   to do at that point.....